# Conversion of NSData to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am converting NSData to NSString  with following code

```
NSData *videodata=-----?

NSString *urlstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:videodata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

I also tried

```
NSString *urlstring= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[videodata bytes]];
```

But both returns null value.Is there any other process.Thanks

Comment: methods are ok, check your data?

Comment: Do you know it is, in fact, string data? If so, are you certain it's encoded using UTF-8?

Comment: If you don't know how to answer trudyscousin's question, NSLog the NSData and post the results here.

Comment: I am writing above code in if(videodata)

Comment: NSLog(@"Exist");it shows Exist in console.when i print nsdata value it slow down the process,so i am using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSData *somedata = [NSData data];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:somedata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or replace the encoding with the encoding of the data

Comment: This seems to be exactly what the OP already has, except that you're explicitly using an empty NSData instead of one that (presumably) has something in it.

Comment: it was an example i assumed that the somedata would be `videodata` in his example, i was just trying to show how he could create an NSString without a UTF8 encoding (I am guessing the data he obtains isnt UTF8 since his code isnt working)

Comment: What is it an example of? It's the exact same line of code he already has, except that you're passing in an explicitly empty NSData object. That doesn't show how to create an NSString without a UTF8 encoding; it shows how to create an NSString _with_ a UTF8 encoding, which works trivially because '' is a valid empty string in just about any charset. How does that help to figure out what's wrong with his actual NSData?